# Using customized acumatica report designer reports in a different instance

Tags: acumatica

[SqlException (0x80131904): Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int]
PX.Common.Async.Process(String uniqueKey, Method`1 method, Int64 waitTimeout) +398
PX.Reports.Web.WebReport.Render(HttpResponse response, String format, Int32 pageNumber, Boolean refresh, Boolean isAttacment, String locale) +1574
PX.Reports.Web.PageOperation.PerformOperation(NameValueCollection urlQuery, HttpResponse response) +329
PX.Reports.Web.HttpHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +237
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +872
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +220
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +94

Comment: It may be helpful to give a bit more context to your problem.  From the error, it would seem that somewhere you're trying to use an ``int`` type for a non-``int`` field.

Comment: Yeah the posited scenario and the posted error don't seem to have much in common. Context is helpful here, and I believe it's also required in order to be considered a stackable question in the first place.